# JavaScript arrays behave like PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Is there a way to assign values in a JavaScript array in the way I do it in PHP.

For example in PHP I can do that:

```
$ar = array();
$ar[] = "Some value";
$ar[] = "Another value";
```

Is that posible to be done with JavaScript? Or if not is there any similar way ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The direct translation of your original code is

```
var ar = [];
ar[ar.length] = "Some value";
ar[ar.length] = "Another value";
```

However a better looking solution is to use the pretty universal `push` method:

```
var ar = [];
ar.push("Some value");
ar.push("Another value");
```

Answer (score 8):

As with most languages, JavaScript has an implementation of [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add an item to the end of an array.

```
var ar = [];
ar.push("Some value");
ar.push("Another value");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push('value1');
myArray.push('value1');
```

Or

```
var myArray = [];
myArray[myArray.length] = 'value0';
myArray[myArray.length] = 'value1';
myArray[myArray.length] = 'value2';
```

Check out this reference document for more about javascript arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Arrays are treated slightly different in javascript. In PHP, an array like this:

PHP

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray[1] = 'value';
$myArray[10] = 'value';
echo count($myArray); // output: 2
```

Javascript:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray[1] = 'value';
myArray[10] = 'value';


console.log(myArray.length); // output: 11
```

What's going on here? In PHP, an array is an dynamic container. The indexes needn't be sequential - indeed, there is little difference between an associative array (an array with string indexes instead of numeric ones) and a standard array.

In javascript, the concept of "associative array" does not exists in the array context - these would be object literals instead (`{}`). The **array** object in javascript is sequential. If you have an index `10`, you must also have the indexes before 10; 9,8,7, etc. Any value in this sequential list that is not explicitly assigned a value will be filled with the value `undefined`:

From the example above:

```
console.log(myArray); //[undefined, "value", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,` undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "value"]
```